# Is it possible to say blessings on matzah and maror on Pesach Sheni?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, matzah, marror-bitter-herbs, pesach-sheni

The fact is that some Hasidim spend on Pesach Sheni a meal almost identical to the Seder. In addition, there are a number of people who were not able to have a seder on the night of Nisan 15 and they want to do it on Pesach Sheni
(so did Rabbi Herschel Schechter for the liberated prisoners of Buchenwald).

Is it possible to bless matzah and maror during such a meal, as in a regular Seder Pesach (al achilas matzo and al achilas moroir) ?

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2013/04/03/pesach-sheini/ I hope this answers your question (the idea basically being that Pesach Sheni nowadays is only a minhag, עיין שם)

Comment: @AvishaiTebeka Your answer didn't answer my question.

Comment: Why doesn't that answer the question (no)?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi That is, as far as I understood, it is impossible to read "al achilas matzo" and "al achilas moroir"?

Comment: Seems to answer the question? As an aside someone could circumvent the problem (maybe) by reading the blessing out of the Rambam of Talmud/Tosefta from the begining of the halacha. I don't know where this is first discussed but I think it was done in practice at Zecher LeHakel at Kotel. Nonetheless, ashkenazim at least, do not typically allow pronouncing the blessings in Talmud passages with name of Hashem during study

Comment: I don't understand how that link doesn't answer your question, can you please elaborate so I can explain the answer?

Comment: @AvishaiTebeka Sorry, I didn't find the right section right away. Now I got the answer to my question.